# login root path / on symfony instead /login

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

```
<!-- templates/bootstrap/login/form-login.html.twig-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="padding-right: 0px;" class="col-12">
            <form method="post">

              <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
              <input type="email" value="{{ last_username }}" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" autocomplete="email" required autofocus>
              <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" required>

              <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
                     value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
              >

              {% if error %}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
              {% endif %}

              {% if app.user %}
                  <div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="mb-3">
                      You are logged in as {{ app.user.username }}, <a href="{{ path('app_logout') }}">Logout</a>
                  </div>
              {% endif %}

              <button style="margin-top: 10px; width: 100%;" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                  Sign in
              </button>
            </form>

            <div style="border-top: 1px solid black; height: 1px;margin-top: 10px;"></div>

            <a style="width: 100%;" href="/registration" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Create an account</a>

            <div style="height: 1px;margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All work correctly on "http://webserver5.com:8001/login" path.
But It doesn't work on "http://webserver5.com:8001/" path.
If I enter email and password correctly or incorrectly I obtain only refresh page. Why?
I want "/" root path because to point a login method controller.
Can you help me please.

Comment: How does your route for `/` path looks like?

Comment: Thanks. app_welcome:
  path: /
  controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::login

Comment: path / is connected to SecurityController::login not work. instead path /login work. Are the same. Path /login point to App\Controller\SecurityController::login

Comment: Please share more details about your debugging attempts

Comment: Maybe you are logged in but redirected back to `/` path (by default). Check your debug toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_welcome';

    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {

        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_contact_index'));
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

```
    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_welcome';
```

This route app_welcome is defined thus:
/
App\Controller\SecurityController::login

Now it works.